# Grid table with uneven gaps

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a sudoku game. To display grid I use the following code:

**CSS**

```
.gamegrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 50px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 50px);
    gap: 5px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="gamegrid">
    <div class="cell" data-id="a1">1</div>
    <div class="cell" data-id="a2">2</div>
    <div class="cell" data-id="a3">3</div>
    <div class="cell" data-id="a4">4</div>
    ...77 more lines
</div>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Sudoku boad]

The board is hard to read because of even spacing.
I would like to make it such that every 3rd row and column spacing is say 10 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using `gap` as this is consistent across all rows/columns given your current structure.

Frankly though I would use 9 separate 9 cell grids, might make it easier than an 81 cell grid.

Result
[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 160px);
  gap: 10px;
}

.cell-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-box">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used it and I am happy with the result :)